# How to get the object value that is inside multiple arrays using angular and typescript?

Tags: typescript, angular6

I need help getting the item and color value of each of the array  inside the total array

This is an example of my json

```
 "results ": {
"totals": {
  "total": [
    {
      "item": "car",
      "color": "red"
    },
    {
      "item": "car",
      "color": "white"
    },
    {
      "item": "bike",
      "color": "green"
    }
  ]
},
```

This is the typescript code I'm using the get the item  and color from my json response

```
  let i = 0;
         this .items = response.results.totals.total.forEach((x)=>
              {
                this .item = x.item ;
                this .color = x.color;
               i++
              }
```

HTML

```
 <pre><strong>Item</strong>{{item}}</pre>
  <pre><strong>Color</strong>{{color}}</pre>
```

When I run my code I'm only able to display the  first array inside the total array

```
Items : car 
Color: red
```

How I can get all the values inside the total array  and display in my page  using html so my output look like this ?

```
Items : car
Color: red
Items : car
Color: white
Items : bike
Color: green
```

Comment: You are not looping in your html as far as I can see, also not sure if just a typo in SO but you shouldn't have spaces after this for example `(this. item)`

Comment: Would recommend an `*ngfor` loop then you won't even need to create a loop in your typescript

Answer (score 1):

```js
this.items = response.results.totals.total;
```

Set the `this.items` as the array of the items you want to display.

And use `ngFor` for displaying the items in html:

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <pre><strong>Item</strong>{{item.item}}</pre>
  <pre><strong>Color</strong>{{item.color}}</pre>
</div>
```